# Draggable element overflows container on drop

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When user is trying to drop the element in the droppable zone the dragged element lies half inside the droppable zone and other part out of the container

Comment: check your code. i think you have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: show your sample code

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `.prop('scrollWidth')` is greater than the container's `.outerWidth()`. If so, resize or re-position the dropped element.